# print() en diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x

Soy nueva en Python y estoy realizando el siguiente ejercicio: Escribe un programa que lee las palabras en words.txt y las almacena como claves en un diccionario. No importa qué valores tenga. Luego puedes utilizar el operador in como una forma rápida de revisar si una cadena está en el diccionario.

logré hacerlo satisfactoriamente, sin embargo, tengo una duda: El primer print() si imprime y el segundo no. ¿por qué?

```
handle= open('words.txt')
palab=dict()
count=0
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip().split()
    long=len(line)
    if long <1:  #protector
        exit()
    for word in line:
        if word in palab:continue #duplicados
        count+=1
        palab[word]=count
    print(palab) #si imprime
        
print(palab) #no imprime
```

Comment: si el programa sale con el `exit()`, la línea del `print()` que está fuera del ciclo nunca llega a ejecutarse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Listo, publiqué una respuesta, para que quede por si a alguien más le sirve. Bienvenida, te invito a hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo, te dejo también tu primer voto positivo!.

Answer (score 0):

No es que el segundo print no imprima.

El problema es que esa línea no llega a ejecutarse.

Esto debido a que estás usando [`exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit) lo que provoca que el programa termine en ese momento (tras bambalinas eleva una excepción).

Podrías terminar el ciclo con `break`, lo que provocaría que se ejecute la siguiente instrucción después del mismo, que es justamente ese print:

```
handle= open('words.txt')
palab=dict()
count=0
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip().split()
    long=len(line)
    if long <1:  #protector
        break
    for word in line:
        if word in palab:continue #duplicados
        count+=1
        palab[word]=count
    print(palab) 
        
print(palab)
```

De todas maneras, según la propia documentación no debieras utilizar `exit()` en código que está en producción, así que mejor si no te acostumbras a utilizarlo.

Comment: Gracias, lo corregiré de esa manera!

Comment: Excelente @Sofia. Pude ver que no has hecho el [tour]. Te invito a hacerlo y también que aprendas [que cosas puedes hacer si alguien te responde](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez yo no esté entendiendo el problema, pero leo el enunciado ejecuto tu código y... no parecen estar consustanciados... (perdón por el "palabro").

El enunciado pide leer una entrada, y usar las palabras como "key" de un diccionario, tu código separa en letras...

```
entrada = open('words.txt')

   # modifico para ejemplificar un resultado
entrada = 'Si hay humo y en caso de incendio grite en caso'
palabras = dict()
count = 0

   # creamos un array de palabras a partir de la entrada  
texto = tt.rstrip().split(" ")

   # recorremos el array
for palabra in texto:
    
       # acá no se que intención tenías, modifiqué para eliminar palabras cortas
       # se puede obviar
    long = len( palabra )
    if long < 4:  #protector
        continue
   
       # verificamos si la palabra ya está en el diccionario, si no está, 
       # la agregamos y aumentamos el contador
    if palabra in palabras:
        continue #duplicados
    else:
        count += 1
        palabras[ palabra ] = count
    print( palabras ) 
        
print( palabras )
```

esto imprime:

```
{'humo': 1}
{'humo': 1, 'caso': 2}
{'humo': 1, 'caso': 2, 'incendio': 3}
{'humo': 1, 'caso': 2, 'incendio': 3, 'grite': 4}
{'humo': 1, 'caso': 2, 'incendio': 3, 'grite': 4} # esta linea es del último "print"
```